# Why does a basic optimal variable have positive reduced cost?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

Why does a a basic optimal variable have reduced cost positive in a minimization problem?

The lp model is as follows:

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name: IloCplex

Minimize
obj: 325255008 y(1) + 207016000 y(2) + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1)
  + 511.284124007454 x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3) + 4201096 lambda(1)
  + 8400658 lambda(2) + 21000220 lambda(3)

Subject To

r_beta_1_2:             x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1) + x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2)
                     + x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) + x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3) + x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3) + x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1)  = 1

r_beta_2_1:             x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2) + x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2)
                     + x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) + x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3) + x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) + x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)  = 1

r_delta_1_2_1:          - y(1) + x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                     + x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2) + x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3) + x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1) <= 0

r_delta_1_2_2:          - y(2) + x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2)
                     + x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) + x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3)
                     + x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3) + x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 0

r_delta_2_1_1:          - y(1) + x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2) + x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3) + x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1) <= 0

r_delta_2_1_2:          - y(2) + x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2)
                     + x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) + x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3)
                     + x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2) + x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 0

r_piI_1_2:              y(1) + x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) + x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 1

r_piI_2_1:              y(2) + x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2) + x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) <= 1

r_piJ_1_2:              y(2) + x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1) + x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3) <= 1

r_piJ_2_1:              y(1) + x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) + x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2)
                     + x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 1

r_gamma_1_2_1_2:        17.7232875823975 x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
                     - 200 lambda(1) - 300 lambda(2) - 500 lambda(3) <= 0

r_gamma_1_2_2_3:        17.7232875823975 x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 0

r_gamma_1_2_3_1:        17.7232875823975 x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 0

r_gamma_2_1_1_2:        17.7232875823975 x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 0

r_gamma_2_1_2_3:        17.7232875823975 x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2)
                     - 200 lambda(1) - 300 lambda(2) - 500 lambda(3) <= 0

r_gamma_2_1_3_1:        17.7232875823975 x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1)
                     + 17.7232875823975 x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 0

c17:                    lambda(1) - Rgc17  = 0
c18:                    lambda(2) - Rgc18  = 0
c19:                    lambda(3) - Rgc19  = 0

r_casamento_y_lambda_1: y(1) - lambda(1) - lambda(2) - lambda(3) <= 0
r_casamento_y_lambda_2: y(2) - lambda(1) - lambda(2) - lambda(3) <= 0

Bounds

0 <= y(1) <= 1
0 <= y(2) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,3) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,2,3,1,1,3,3,3,3) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,3) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,1) <= 1
0 <= x(2,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,3) <= 1
0 <= lambda(1) <= 1
0 <= lambda(2) <= 1
0 <= lambda(3) <= 1
0 <= Rgc17 <= 3
0 <= Rgc18 <= 3
0 <= Rgc19 <= 3

End
```

I'm worried with lambdas vairables.

When I solve this model directly by the terminal using cplex, I can get this information :

Display which part of the solution: reduced
Display reduced costs for which variable(s): lambda(1)
Variable Name             Reduced Cost
lambda(1)              -4199562.000000

CPLEX> display solution reduced
Display reduced costs for which variable(s): lambda(2)
The reduced cost 'lambda(2)' is 0.

CPLEX> display solution reduced
Display reduced costs for which variable(s): lambda(3)
Variable Name             Reduced Cost
lambda(3)              12599562.000000

CPLEX> display solution variables
Display values of which variable(s): lambda(1)
Variable Name           Solution Value
lambda(1)                     1.000000

CPLEX> display solution variables 
Display values of which variable(s): lambda(2)
The variable 'lambda(2)' is 0.

CPLEX> display solution variables 
Display values of which variable(s): lambda(3)
The variable 'lambda(3)' is 0.

Is that ok?

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f0ba459e-0e0b-4f31-95de-24e548535f48&ps=25).

Comment: Please don't cross post. It makes any effort to answer feel worthless.

Answer (score 1):

A variable can be non-basic if it is at one of its bounds (i.e. lower-bound or upper-bound). (Detail: free variable are special: they can be nonbasic between bounds -- sometimes called superbasic). So all variables λ are  potentially non-basic when we look at the values. The reduced cost indicate that λ1 and λ3 must be non-basic and λ2 can be basic or non-basic (if the solution is degenerate). Use `display solution basis` to find all basic variables.

The sign of the reduced cost depends if the variable is nonbasic upper or nonbasic lower. It basically indicates how the objective can change if the corresponding bound changes. A positive rc for λ3 looks fine to me. (It is non-basic and not basic as you seem to think).

Comment: Sorry! But I didn't understand.
You said that "A variable can be non-basic if it is at one of its bounds". All lambda variables are in its bound, aren't they? Their bounds are 0 and 1. lambda(1) = 1; lambda(2) = lambda(3) = 0.
Non basic variables don't have to be equal zero?
I thought that only the basic variables were able to be equal some value different from zero.
When use "display solution basis", I found that lambda(1) and lambda(3) are non-basic variables. The basic variable is lambda(2). 
But I didn't get why.

Comment: If 0 <= x <= 1 then if x=1 it is quite likely it is nonbasic. Any variable at bound (lower or upper) with rc<>0 is non-basic.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. But, then, in this case, what is the stopping criterion of Simplex? I thought it always was having all non basic variables with positive reduced cost (in a minimization problem).

Comment: `x(i)` is a candidate to enter the basis  (1)  if it can increase and `sigma(i)<0` or (2) if it can decrease and `sigma(i)>0`.. If no candidates can be found then the solution is optimal. See any book on linear programming (chapter on bounded revised simplex method).